# Finding volume of a solid with square cross section

Tags: calculus

If I had a solid whose cross sections are squares perpendicular to the $x$-axis with their center on the axis, a graph is shown below

[image: Graph]

We have $x^{2}$ and $-x^{2}$ from $0$ to $1$, and we want to calculate the volume, would it be correct to say that the square has side edge
$$x^{2}+x^{2}=2x^{2}$$
and therefore,
$$V= \int_{0}^{1} \left( 2x^{2} \right)^{2} \;dx = \int_{0}^{1} 4x^{4}\;dx=\dfrac{4x^{5}}{5}\bigg]_{0}^{1}=\dfrac{4}{5}$$

Is this correct in finding the volume?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.